# Алгоритм журналирования транзакции

Tags: concurrency

При работе над текущим проектом появился сложный случай транзакции, которая должна сработать безотказно, но сама по себе атомарной не является. Само приложение представляет собой небольшой сервис биллинга, который может горизонтально масштабироваться и использует одно распределенное хранилище данных (cassandra).

Приложение, помимо прочего, оперирует сущностью баланса:

```
{
    "accountId": "admin",
    "currencyBalances": {
        "RUB": 200.22,
        "USD": 10
    },
    "createdAt": 0,
    "updatedAt": 1400000000
}
```

и применяемой к балансу операции ввода или вывода средств

```
{
    "accountId": "admin",
    "currency": "RUB",
    "amount": -100.0
}
```

Когда операция создается, она должна отобразиться в двух местах: в виде записи самой операции и в виде изменения баланса. Хранилище не дает мне сделать это атомарно, и мне нужен алгоритм, который позволит восстановить целостность системе, которая упадет между двумя записями в БД.

Сама по себе задача тривиальна (запись о необходимости установить целостность для операции Х в журнал -> создание записи Х -> установление целостности, в случае падения экземпляра приложения журнал непроведенных операций считывается и воспроизводится -> запись в журнале удаляется), но я ограничен некоторыми рамками приложения и сопутствующих сервисов:

- Хранилище имеет механизм транзакционности только для операций над одним ключом, поэтому я не могу атомарно сделать сразу две записи. Из-за этого я не могу обновить сам баланс и сделать об этом запись в соседней таблице - система имеет право упасть между этими двумя записями, равно как и хранилище может оказаться недоступным при выполнении одной из записей.
- Все сущности хранятся в виде лога манипуляций над ними (event sourcing).  Баланс может выглядеть так:

  ```
  [ {
    "entityType": "doe.john.Balance",
    "entityId": "admin"
    "eventType": "doe.john.BalanceChangedEvent",
    "event": {
       "timestamp": 1400000000,
       "currency": "RUB",
       "amount": 500,
       "operationId": "408279ae-ee9a-46f3-a9d2-88b0e13d476e"
    },
    "version": 1
  },
  {
    "entityType": "doe.john.Balance",
    "entityId": "admin"
    "eventType": "doe.john.BalanceChangedEvent",
    "event": {
       "timestamp": 1400000001,
       "currency": "RUB",
       "amount": 100,
       "operationId": "87fb18b0-3b01-477f-b959-21b22d54af1f"
    },
    "version": 2
  },
  {
    "entityType": "doe.john.Balance",
    "entityId": "admin"
    "eventType": "doe.john.BalanceChangedEvent",
    "event": {
       "timestamp": 1400000002,
       "currency": "EUR",
       "amount": 10,
       "operationId": "464608fd-d737-454a-8278-9c56fa52f9d6"
    },
    "version": 3
  } ]
  ```

  Что в конечном счете преобразуется последовательным применением в

  ```
  {
      "accountId": "admin",
      "currencyBalances": {
          "RUB": 600,
          "EUR": 10
      },
      "updatedAt": 1400000002,
      "createdAt": 1400000000
  }
  ```

  Это забирает у меня возможность перерасчитать баланс пользователя целиком: я могу только добавлять новые манипуляции, но не могу изменять старые (это аналогично удалению связанных сущностей в РСУБД). Ровно так же я не могу проверить, применялась ли операция к балансу: я могу только получить `operationId` для конкретной манипуляции (непосредственно манипуляции записываются в виде JSON-строк, хранилище поддерживает поиск только по точным значениям). Указывать все `operationId` прямо в собранной сущности баланса я не могу, т.к. это потенциально бесконечный список. Кроме вышеописанных минусов, данный формат подразумевает добавление в режиме оптимистичной блокировки (вычисляется следующий `version` и используется в `INSERT ... IF NOT EXISTS`), поэтому обновления другим процессом обнаруживаются тривиально.
- Распределенные блокировки теоретически возможны, но могут окончательно добить всю производительность, их хотелось бы избежать, пока это возможно. Ставить какие-либо флаги на записи (e.g. "данная запись в данный момент редактируется") бессмысленно в силу архитектуры хранилища.
- Приложение горизонтально масштабируется, точное число узлов в конкретный момент времени неизвестно. Есть вероятность, что журналированную операцию будут выполнять сразу несколько узлов, до этого сценария это было принято как неизбежное зло, и все операции просто были идемпотентными.

Таким образом, мне необходимо осуществить две записи (с точки зрения приложения - осуществить две манипуляции), при этом у меня есть проблемы в определении, была ли осуществлена вторая запись/манипуляция (я могу получить манипуляцию по конкретному id / версии, но не могу определить ее существование по `operationId`). Так или иначе мне требуется реализовать некоторый алгоритм журналируемой системы, который предварительно запишет предстоящую операцию, а потом сможет установить целостность системы вне зависимости от количества его вызовов.

В данный момент есть идея только одного алгоритма:

1. Получается текущая версия баланса
2. Процесс получает текущую запись операции. Если в ней содержатся сведения о том, что она была полностью применена, процесс считает, что целостность записи достигнута и прекращается
3. Процесс проверяет наличие записей в таблице-журнале о том, в какой ожидаемой версии (манипуляции) операция будет отражена в балансе.

   - Если такая запись существует, процесс проверяет наличие соответствующей версии баланса

     - Если такая версия (манипуляция) существует и она действительно соответствует применению текущей операции, процесс сразу переходит к п.5
     - Если такая версия существует и в ней записано применение иной операции, процесс перезаписывает запись журнала с указанием новой версии
     - Если такой версии еще не существует (а это может быть только в том случае, если версия следует сразу за текущей), процесс ничего не делает на данном этапе
   - Если такой записи не существует, процесс создает ее
4. Процесс пытается создает манипуляцию и пытается применить ее к балансу. В случае, если манипуляция проваливается, это означает, что версия баланса сменилась, и процесс нужно запускать с начала.
5. Процесс обновляет операцию, указывая в ней сведения о том, что она была полностью применена.

Как можно видеть, алгоритм абсолютно дикий, и я сильно не уверен в безопасности пункта 3. Я уверен, что это все - велосипедная конструкция, и есть гораздо более оптимальные способы разрешить эту ситуацию, которые, если кто-то их знает, хотелось бы услышать.

UPD

Благодаря магическим способностям моего коллеги (напрочь отстутствующим у меня) удалось найти рациональное решение и превратить всю задачу в простой автомат, который, кажется, работает. В дополнение к вышеописанной ситуации добавляются условия:

1. Операция может иметь состояния PENDING (выставляется при создании), PROCESSING, PROCESSED.
2. Баланс сохраняет в себе множество операций, находящихся в обработке; считается, что в нормально работающей системе это множество не будет неограниченно расти из-за временных рамок.

Задача выполняется следующим образом (∋ означает наличие операции в списке незавершенных операций баланса):

```
n | Статус операции | ∋ | Следующий шаг
1 | ?               | ? | Чтение баланса
2 | ?               | - | Чтение операции
3 | PENDING         | - | Добавить операцию в незавершенные
4 | PENDING         | + | Сменить статус операции на PROCESSING
5 | PROCESSING      | + | Применить операцию, одновременно удалив ее из незавершенных
6 | PROCESSING      | - | Сменить статус операции на PROCESSED
7 | PROCESSED       | - | Yay!
```

Дело осталось за формальным доказательством работоспособности (или неработоспособности) данного автомата (и с этим у меня плохо, я это пока не умею). Порядок переходов 0-1 и 1-2 необходим для того, чтобы предотвратить повторный переход 2-3 после перехода 5-6. Обновление каждой сущности атомарно, в случае, если сущность оказалась в каком-то ином состоянии, ее версия сменится, что позволит сбросить алгоритм на начало.

Comment: Три раза прочел и ничего не понял. Какова все-таки логическая схема данных. Этих пар {валюта, количество} много экземпляров? Просто если они различаются лишь валютой, то их м.б. сотни (ну, тысячи) и непонятно в чем вообще проблема. (и пожалуйста, пишите попроще (не для выступления в АН)).

Comment: @avp переписал все

Answer (score 1):

возможно Batch transaction Вам поможет.

Comment: Если я все верно понимаю, то, боюсь, не помогут - batch **statement** гарантирует, что все запросы будут выполнены с одним timestamp, и что они будут повторяться, пока все соответствующие узлы не ответят корректно, но они не спасут меня от того, что одна сущность обновилась, а вторая - нет, и я опять окажусь в состоянии многократного применения операции http://stackoverflow.com/a/30709482/2908793

Comment: в [описании](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/batch_r.html) сказано что транзакция полностью атомарна. Есть как логируемые так и не логируемые транзакции. Опять же, `TIMESTAMP` можно отдельно указать для каждой операции в транзакции. вот пример
`BEGIN BATCH
  INSERT INTO purchases (user, balance) VALUES ('user1', -8) USING TIMESTAMP 19998889022757000;
  INSERT INTO purchases (user, expense_id, amount, description, paid)
    VALUES ('user1', 1, 8, 'burrito', false);
APPLY BATCH;`

Comment: Она не может быть атомарна by design. Timestamp меня никак не спаасет: представьте, что я делаю два идентичных BATCH STATEMENT с разных концов кластера. В результате противоположные концы кластера в этот момент содержат разные состояния и тем самым нарушают целостность, равно как и все мои алгоритмы, которые основываются на том, что применение любого нового состояния атомарно и не может откатиться назад.

Comment: На всякий продублировал http://stackoverflow.com/q/37299075/2908793